# Parsing HTTP Response to spreadsheet (error'94': invalid use of null)

Tags: vba, http, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

I am using VBA for sending HTTP Request and parse Response to my spreadsheet. while decoding table data from response, I am getting "error'94': invalid use of null".
code is given below. HTML structure of response link is also shared. Please Help..

Image-1
[image: Image-1: Here is the Image of Error and line where is comes]

Image-2
[image: Image-2: snapshot of the HTML Response msg where desired data reside]

Here is a link `[a link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_ubH3zyPiZ8crK-KYs_-RipkGDoFci9G/view?usp=sharing)!`

```
URL = "https://xx.xxxx.com/itrade/user/watch.exe?action=C "
xmlhttp.Open "POST", URL, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Host", "xx.xxxx.com"
.....
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Cookie", cook

xmlhttp.send bodyk


html.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText
'---------Done-----------
getcookres = xmlhttp.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
Worksheets("Action").Cells(3, 24).Value = getcookres


Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long
Set nodeList = html.querySelectorAll("#data_table tr.tinside td")
For i = 1 To nodeList.Length - 1
    Debug.Print nodeList.Item(i).innerText
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i).Value = nodeList.Item(i).innerText
Next

Worksheets("Action").Cells(6, 26).Value = Worksheets("Action").Cells(6, 27).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you share the failing VBA and any associated error messages? Typically you can remove all the sec- headers without a problem but you can use a tool like Postman to check which headers are needed. You might need to dynamically pick up a header value such as that for cookie.

Comment: I checked the complete response by saving it in text file, and understand that I am receiving desired data. I guess there is issue in parsing data into excel. codes and data are following

Comment: @QHarr Here is the code I use

`'# HTTP Req Sent #

'#Responce part:

xmlhttp.send bodyk

html.body.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText

getcookres = xmlhttp.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
Worksheets("Action").Cells(3, 24).Value = getcookres

'Decode Responce here
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long
Set nodeList = html.querySelectorAll("#data_table tr.tinside td")
For i = 1 To nodeList.Length - 1
    Debug.Print nodeList.Item(i).innerText
        Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i).Value = nodeList.Item(i).innerText
Next`

Comment: As there are currently no answers to this question, you might be better using [edit] to update the title, add in your formatted code, and explain the problem as you know understand it. Be sure to include any error messages and where they occur as well as expected versus actual results.

Comment: Here is the Response which contain data table.  [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_ubH3zyPiZ8crK-KYs_-RipkGDoFci9G/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Edit is done..!! Please help

Comment: `Dim nodeList As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection`

Comment: thankyou very much. This solved the Problem..!!